# Find anchor tag value inside li and ul and div tag using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have just started my career. I got one requirement of getting the value inside an anchor tag which is inside div, ul and li tags.

```
<div class="abc">
    <ul><li><a>Test</a></li><li class="selected"><a>Test</a></li><ul>
</div>
```

I want to fetch the anchor tag value which is under li tag having class selected using javascript. The hierarchy starts from div-ul-li

I know to get the values by using document.getElementyId, but this looks like  complex for me

Any ideas would be very helpful for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: This is a good starting point: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: i can understand you are initial with code also using stackoverflow too so u should see check how to post questions and stuff first.
**You can get text from selected class a**: `document.querySelector("ul li.selected a").text`

Comment: Thank  you shubhanu ji. But I want the text of that anchor tag which is under that particular div tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use the **whole** hierarchy?

In this case, `querySelector` is your friend. The query looks like this:

`querySelector('div.abc > ul > li.selected > a')`.

In detail that means:

- `div.abc` gets us the div with the class `abc`
- `>` refers to a child element of the element left to `>`, so we referr to `ul` which is a child node of your `div abc`
- Now we want the `div` with the class `selected` which is a child node of `ul`, so we use `>` again
- Last but not least we want to access the `a` tag inside of the `div selected`. Again we'll do that by using `>`

```js
var text = document.querySelector('div.abc > ul > li.selected > a').textContent;

console.log(text);
```

```html
<div class="abc">
  <ul>
    <li><a>Test</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a>Test</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```